# How to download a webpage developed in AngularJS that renders iframes, as a PDF file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, pdf, iframe

There is a webpage which uses iframes. The iframes can be used to embed videos(youtube/vimeo), websites(any), documents(.txt and .pdf) , and worksheets from Tableau. The no. of iframes and the content they load is dynamic within the context mentioned in the previous point. Along with the iframes, the webpage has some regular text content and images. How can we download this webpage ensuring we retain its layout and iframe content? (The download feature has to be a part of the webpage we are trying to download which is a part of an application developed in AngularJS.). I have tried using jsPDF and other PDF utilities(https://github.com/hearsid/ng-html-to-pdf-save) but they fail to render the iframe content.

Anyone who has come across a similar problem, please help. 
Like

Answer (score 0):

There is one solution is to use wkhtmltopadf, you should install the package in your machine and after that you can use it.

it's  a very robust library that render vectoriel pdf instead of other library that render bitmap.

[Official web site](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/)